# error in using wikipedia api

Tags: asp.net, api, wikipedia-api

i am using wikipedia api to fetch data from wiki pedia but i am getting error here iam posting my code and my error. Please help me.

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&search=hello");
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
{
    string ResponseText;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        ResponseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    lblresult.Text = ResponseText;
}
```

Here is my error:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at _Default.btnsearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Imran Ali\Desktop\Wikipedia\Default.aspx.cs:line 33
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Does the server also return any *text* in the error page? That might tell you why you are getting 403. I don't get a 403 making the same API request, so maybe they blocked your IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access Wikipedia (using the API or not), you have to set a [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in the request. This is because of [Wikimedia's User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

What to set the User-Agent header to? Quoting the policy page linked above:

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

How to set the header? Use [the `UserAgent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx) on the request object.

As a side note, for simple requests like this, it's easier to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) methods, for example, `DownloadString()`.